# How to set parameters for an API POST query using Python and JSON

Tags: python, json, api, post

I'm querying a real estate API using Python (`requests`), with POST data submitted in JSON format.
I'm getting responses as expected - however each time I want to make a query I'm editing the fields in a hardcoded JSON object in the .py file.

I'd like to do something a bit more robust - eg using a user prompt to populate the JSON object to be submitted, based on the API search schema (see [JSON file (pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/xnhJ6maL)) (open to alternative python based solutions to this).

The linked schema includes the full list of parameters available to query - I'll likely trim this down to the ones that are most relevant to the queries that I'm building/POSTing, so that there are less parameters to deal with. I'd like to know of a Pythonic way to cycle through the Parameters in the Schema and then add the ones I wish to submit for a query to the JSON object?

TIA.

Comment: can you post an example of what you are hardcoding today? or example of what you'd like as end result?

Comment: [Here's a chunk of the code](https://pastebin.com/H8v1GJX1) - I set the parameters in the `for_sale_base` dict then the functions below iterate other variables like the postcode and/or suburb name and re-submit the query, adding the results to a dataframe as I go. I'd like to run the script and use and input prompt to set the parameters to be included in the base dict - rather than having to remember them and scrolling through the code to change settings.

Comment: ah, ok now I get what you want to do. Unfortunately, using user prompts and interactive code is a bit out of wheelhouse. Good luck.